# SendGrid: Disable Clicktrack using Node

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-nodejs

I am using the [sendgrid-nodejs](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs) library to send emails using SendGrid.
I want to disable click-tracking on a per-email basis.

I understand that you can [include an attribute](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/analytics-and-reporting/click-tracking-html-best-practices) within dynamic templates to disable click tracking:

> Click tracking can be turned off for individual links by including the `clicktracking=off` attribute inside the anchor of an HTML link before the href. For example, `<a clicktracking=off href="http://example.com">link text</a>` would not be tracked.

However, I wish to control this programmatically.

According to SendGrid documentation, it is possible to disable click-tracking by using the [clicktrack filter](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/smtp-filters#filter-clicktrack):

```json
{
  "filters": {
    "clicktrack": {
      "settings": {
        "enable": 0,
        "enable_text": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Looking at the [Mail constructor](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/main/packages/helpers/classes/mail.js#L85), it appears we have the ability to set headers. The type bindings indicate it expects header values to be a string.

```bash
headers?: { [key: string]: string }
```

Note: I can confirm this per SendGrid's error return (if attempting to pass an object):

```json
{
  "body": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid type. Expected: string, given: object.",
        "field": "headers",
        "help": "http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#message.headers"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Regardless of what I pass, nothing seems to have any impact. The emails are being sent successfully, but click-tracking is not being disabled.

```js
const { SENDGRID_KEY } = process.env
const mail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
mail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_KEY)

mail.send({
  headers: {
    // this doesn't have any impact
    "X-SMTPAPI": JSON.stringify({
      filters: {
        clicktrack: {
          settings: {
            enable: 0,
            enable_text: false
          }
        }
      }
    }),
    // neither does this
    "filters": JSON.stringify({
      clicktrack: {
        settings: {
          enable: 0,
          enable_text: false
        }
      }
    }),
  },
  to: 'somebody@email.com',
  from: 'nobody@email.com',
  templateId: 'd-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  dynamic_template_data: {
    subject: 'Hello World'
  }
})
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 4):

I've found my [answer](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send). There is a `trackingSettings` property available:

```js
const { SENDGRID_KEY } = process.env
const mail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
mail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_KEY)

mail.send({
  trackingSettings: {
    clickTracking: {
      enable: false,
      enableText: false
    }
  },
  to: 'somebody@email.com',
  from: 'nobody@email.com',
  templateId: 'd-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  dynamic_template_data: {
    subject: 'Hello World'
  }
})
```